# Can't bold or change text size in a word table created by VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

The VB selects the table in a word doc and adds rows to it. It should also be able to bold certain rows and change the font size but it doesn't

I set the data with

```
Public Sub TableSetCellValue(ByVal tableIndex As Integer, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal colIndex As Integer, ByVal value As String)

    wordDoc.Tables(tableIndex).Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex).Range.Text = value

End Sub
```

and I should be able to bold it with

```
Public Sub TableRowFontWeight(ByVal tableIndex As Integer, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal bold As Boolean)

    wordDoc.Tables(tableIndex).Rows(rowIndex).Range.Bold = bold

End Sub
```

When I execute the following code

```
        writer.TableRowFontWeight(currTableIndex, currTableRowIndex, True)
        writer.TableSetCellValue(currTableIndex, currTableRowIndex, 0, column1)
```

It writes the text but doesn't bold the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it using openXML

```
Using wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(FilePath, True)
            Dim wordCell = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements(Of Table).ElementAt(tableIndex).Elements(Of TableRow).ElementAt(rowIndex).Elements(Of TableCell).ElementAt(colIndex)
            Dim tempText = ""
            Dim bold As New Bold()
            'bold.Val = True
            Dim font As New FontSize()
            font.Val = "18"

            For Each para In wordCell.Elements(Of Paragraph)()
                If para.Elements(Of Run).Count > 0 Then
                    If para.Elements(Of Run).First.Elements(Of Text).Count > 0 Then
                        If weight = True Then
                            Dim runProperties As RunProperties = para.Elements(Of Run).First.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
                            runProperties.AppendChild(New RunProperties(font))
                            para.Elements(Of Run).First.AppendChild(New Text(value))
                        Else
                            Dim runProperties As RunProperties = para.Elements(Of Run).First.AppendChild(New RunProperties(font))
                            para.Elements(Of Run).First.AppendChild(New Text(value))
                        End If
                        For i = para.Elements(Of Run)().Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
                            para.Elements(Of Run).ElementAt(i).Remove()
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End Using
```